# Spinnaker attach servers to specific AWS ALB target group

Tags: spinnaker

current behavior is to match ALB by name and attach server to all target groups, this is really defeating a purpose to have ALB, as a server usually needs to be attached to a specific target group.

according to this: https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver/pull/943
there was a thought to do so, but is it implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this as well - assigning a single target group to a ASG is exactly what I need.

Comment: got some news, this feature is being actively worked on, don't now a timeframe tho

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this ticket/comment: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/1150#issuecomment-247079074

It explains what is implemented so far, and what it's limitations are. But basically you can't use spinnaker atm to add servers to only one target group on ALB.